# second order linear equation with variable coefficient (change of variables)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve

$(t^2+1)u_{tt}+tu_t-u_{xx}=0,$

$u|_{t=0}=0$, and $ u_t|_{t=0}=1.$

Make a change of variables $x=\frac{1}{2}(\xi+\eta)$, $t=\sinh (\frac{1}{2}(\xi-\eta))$ and calculate $u_\xi$, $u_\eta$, $u_{\xi\eta}$.

We have $\xi = \sin t + x$ and $\eta = x-\sin t.$

What to do next can I rearrange the equation as $t^2u_{tt} + tu_t + u_{tt} - u_xx =0$? Then how to solve it?